# How do I make two loops?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyhook

I have PyHook loop

```
hm = pyHook.HookManager()
hm.KeyDown = Ob.on_keyboard_event
hm.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

that initiates `Ob.on_keyboard_event` every time  `event.Ascii` comes around from the keyboard. Because it doesn't recognize layout switch on its own `def keyboard(self)` scans for layout. But `def keyboard_layout(self)` just like `on_keyboard_event` works only after an even has come so there is a lag in 1 character before the layout is changed.
I want to make a second loop out of `def keyboard_layout(self)` so it would independently check layout every 0.5s and change it if needed. Right now it happens as

```
def on_keyboard_event(self, event):

    a = self.keyboard_layout()

    if a == hex(0x4090409):

        win32api.LoadKeyboardLayout("00000409", 1)

    else:

        win32api.LoadKeyboardLayout("00000419", 1)
```